# datatable column title language change with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

I have used below code to translation of datatable column title,

```
angular.module('app')
            .controller('gradeLevelCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$mdDialog', '$timeout', '$q', '$log', '$filter', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', '$compile', '$http', '$rootScope', '$uibModal', '$translate', 'apiService', gradeLevelCtrl])

    function gradeLevelCtrl($scope, $state, $mdDialog, $timeout, $q, $log, $filter, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $compile, $http, $rootScope, $uibModal, $translate, apiService) {

 $scope.getDataTable = function () {
            var vm = this;
            vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function () {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                var bodyData = {
                    schoolId: 1,
                    yearId: 1
                };
                $http.post($rootScope.baseUrl + '/grade/list', bodyData)
                        .success(function (result) {
                            if (result.length < $rootScope.numberOfRecord) {
                                $timeout(function () {
                                    angular.element('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
                                }, 200);
                            }
                            vm.grade = [];
                            var index = 1;
                            var resultData = result.data;
                            angular.forEach(resultData, function (value, key) {}
, vm.grade);
                            defer.resolve(vm.grade);
                        }).error(function (error) {});



 vm.dtColumns = [
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('index').withTitle($translate.instant('TABLE_LABEL_SR_NO')).withOption('searchable',false),,
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle($translate.instant('TABLE_LABEL_NAME')),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('created_at').withTitle('Created at').withOption('searchable',false),,
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('status').withTitle('Status').withOption('className', 'tableStatus'),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('operations').withTitle('Actions').withOption('orderable', false).withOption('className', 'tableActions'),
            ];
        }
```

but while language change ,it not change language of column title,is there any solution for this ?

Comment: You have re-initiate the datatable while language change

Comment: no I havent reinitiate datatable at language change

Comment: Try to do re-initiate datatable while lang change